# WSO2IS - Q: Can Claims be Transformed or Computed

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I work for a University and have been tasked with converting from Shibboleth to WSO2IS. I am struggling with Claims and SAML2 Assertions.

I would like to be able to transform claims in WSO2IS. For instance if a SP expects birthDate in the format of '03-May-1979' and another one expects birthDate in the format of '05/03/1979', as far as I can tell there is no way to do that without having separate LDAP attributes and claims.

I would also like to be able to compute claims. For example if a SP wants an age, and I know a birthDate, could I compute the age and send as an assertion? Or could I combine multiple ldap attributes to create a new claim? Ldap GivenName + SurName = FullName.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use JavaScript as an embedded language to make these kind of computations and transformations.

Is this currently possible or on the roadmap?

Comment: This is possible by writing an extension for SAML Response Building. As of now you need to write in Java. Will that be alright?

Comment: And we have experimented with using JS as an embedded language too... I think a combination of these two should be what you are looking for. Let me cook up a sample and post

Comment: @farasath - Thanks so much. An example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a sample Custom Claim Handler[1]. Go through the code[2] and you should be able to figure out what I have done :).

I have added a README on how to deploy this on IS 5.3.0

[1] https://github.com/mefarazath/CustomClaimHandler

[2] https://github.com/mefarazath/CustomClaimHandler/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wso2/sample/claim/handler/CustomClaimHandler.java